# Macro to detect global scope

Tags: macros, scope, lisp, common-lisp

From what I understand, Common Lisp has no global lexical scope, so if you want to create a global variable you have to use `defvar` instead of `setq`. I'm trying to create a macro that just does this automatically, i.e. I'd like to write

```
(= x 1)
```

and have it "just work" no matter where I am. I imagine the macro would look something like

```
(defmacro = (name value)
  `(,(if (is-global) 'defvar 'setf) ,name ,value))
```

How can I write `is-global`?

Comment: SETF does not create variables, not even local variables.

Comment: "As a programmer, I'm strongly indignant about having to remember this." This is about variable declarations. It's similar to saying that you don't want to write variable declarations/bindings at all, and **only** accepting an array of values as an argument to functions (e.g., `(defun frob-the-bar (&rest args) ...)`).  I'd rather `(defun frob-the-bar (frobber bar &key frobulator) ...)` and *know* the arguments.  In Common Lisp, globals are almost always surrounded by "earmuffs" (i.e., the asterisks around, e.g., **\*standard-output\***), so you *do* usually know what kind of variable you have.

Comment: `(= x 1)` does "just work".  It returns whether `x` is 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Introducing Bindings

> *From what I understand, Common Lisp has no global lexical scope,*

This part is correct, but there are some "typical" workarounds.  There's no canonical implementation, but [searching for **deflexical**](https://www.google.com/search?q=deflexical&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#safe=off&q=%22deflexical%22) can lead you to some implementations.

> *so if you want to* create *a global variable you have to use defvar
>   instead of setq.* (emphasis added)

This is incorrect.  For the most part, you don't really *create* variables.  You introduce bindings into an environment.  The most common way of doing this is with **let** or as arguments to a **function**.  E.g.:

```
(defun foo (bar)
   ;; in here, there's a variable `bar`
   )

(let ((a ...))
  ;; a is bound in here
```

These are lexical bindings, unless the symbol that identifies the variable in the source is declared as special, which in Common Lisp means that it's a dynamically scoped variable.  You can do special declarations like:

```
(defun foo (bar)
   (declare (special bar))
   ;; in here, there's a variable `bar`
   )

(let ((a ...))
  (declare (special a))
  ;; a is bound in here
```

Now, you can also introduce global variables with **defparameter** and **defvar**.  These *globally* declare a variable as special.

### Updating Bindings

In *both* cases, you can use **setq** or **setf** to update the value of a variable.  That is, you can use **setq** or **setf** to update the value of lexical variables as well as special variables.  So you can do:

```
(defparameter *cat* (make-initial-cat))

(let ((cat (some-local-cat)))
  (setf *cat* (make-instance 'cat)) ; update global/dynamic
  (setf cat (make-instance 'cat))   ; update local/lexical
```

**setf** works in both cases, so it sounds like the assignment operator you're looking for is just **setf**.

The issue that it sounds like you're trying to work around is that you're not supposed to use **setf**/**setq** with undeclared variables.  Indeed, that's undefined behavior.  So it sounds like you're trying to make your assignment operator automatically introduce a variable if there's not one in the surrounding environment.  You can't do this, for at least two reasons:

1. How would you know whether to introduce a lexical or dynamic variable?  You can't determine it from the surrounding environment, because if it was already in the surrounding environment, you wouldn't need to introduce it.
2. There's no way to check whether it's already declared as a local or dynamic variable.  There are some workaround alternatives that will work in some cases, but environment access isn't part of standard Common Lisp. (See a related question: [Macro to detect global scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29460766/1281433).  Some implementations do implement the [CLtL2 environnments API](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node102.html).)

Answer (score 3):

Both `defvar` and `defparameter` makes global special variables with dynamic scope. `defvar` will only create variable if it's not already defined. Thus. If you haver a counter and reload your source code it would not be reset if it were defined with `defvar` but it would start over if it was defined with `defparameter`.

`setf` with a symbol as first argument is actually a macro for `setq` and it alters a variable. It does not care if the variable is global, lexical or special.

It is a very bad practise to define new global variables deep inside code. You'll get surprises. Special variables is captured dynamically so you can get behavior very difficult to debug. Thats why we use the naming convention with `*earmuffs*` to differentiate between lexical and special variables.

Anyway, if you just want to make a global variable and make sure the value is set at your desired value use `defparameter`. It will work no matter where you are.

```
(defparameter *test* 10) ; ==> *test*
*test*                   ; ==> 10
```

It is not wise to redefine `=` as it is a function used to check number equality.